# A little help on making a decrypter from a key file?

Tags: python, encryption

Alright, so I've been struggling for DAYS trying to figure this out. I've been assigned to make a code that is labeled something like "cipher.py" that imports an encrypted text file, uses a "key.txt" to decrypt, then write the decrypted information to something like "decrypted.txt"

I keep getting encryptedWords = encryptedWords.replace(str(encryptedFiles[i][1]),str(decryptedFiles[i][0]))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Any idea?

```
key = open("key.txt", "r")
encrypted = open("encrypted.txt","r" )
decrypted = open("decrypted.txt", "w")

encryptedFiles = []
decryptedFiles = []
unencrypt= ""


for line in key:
 linesForKey = line.split()
 currentEncrypted = (line[0])
 currentDecrypted = (line[1])


encryptedFiles.append(currentEncrypted)
decryptedFiles.append(currentDecrypted)

key.close()


##########################################


encryptedWords = []
encryptedString = ""
lines = encrypted.readlines()
for line in lines:
 letter = list(line)
 encryptedWords += letter

for i in range(len(encryptedWords)):
 encryptedWords = encryptedWords.replace(str(encryptedFiles[i][1]),str(decryptedFiles[i][0]))

encrypted.close()
decrypted.write(encryptedWords)
decrypted.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `.replace()` attribute is only for strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). As I see you are `+=`ing, you can just add `encryptedWords` as a string.

`+=`ing works interestingly with lists:

```
>>> array = []
>>> string = ''
>>> string+='hello'
>>> array+='hello'
>>> string
'hello'
>>> array
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> list('hello')
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>>
```

`+=` takes the string and splits must like `list(string)` does. Instead of this, you can either change `encryptedWords` to a string (`encryptedWords = ''`), or you can use `''.join(encryptedWords)` or `' '.join(encryptedWords)` to convert back to a string however you want:

```
>>> array = list('hello')
>>> array
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> ''.join(array)
'hello'
>>> ' '.join(array)
'h e l l o'
>>>
```